# How to add non-english char to MYSQL DB using springs mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to insert Arabic/Hindi language characters using springs MVC.
Sample data: عينة am trying to add. But from jsp when it comes to my controller it looks like: 'Ø¹Ù?Ù?Ø©'.

The same is reflecting to the database.

My jsp as follows:

```
   <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
   <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
   <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><%@ page import = "java.util.ResourceBundle" %> 

  <%
  ResourceBundle resource =  ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/web");
  String UI_PATH=resource.getString("lugmaUiPath");
  String title=resource.getString("dashboardTitle");
  String dashboardURL=resource.getString("dashboardURL");
  %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Lugma - Employee List</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
    maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta content="A fully featured admin theme which can be used to build 
    CRM, CMS, etc." name="description" />
    <meta content="Coderthemes" name="author" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    </head>

  <body>
   <form method="POST" action="new_add">
      <input type="text" name="arabic_name" id="arabic_name" >
   </form>
```

My Controller Code looks like:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/new_add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView employee_new_post(employeeBean 
        employeeBean,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
        response){
            ModelAndView model= null;
            system.out.println(""+employeeBean.getArabic_name)
            return model;
        }
```